# Calculating entropy of a graphical password (Passface)?

Tags: passwords, entropy

I feel like I'm overthinking this as the only online example I've come across is [this paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-13241-4_16), which is using more advanced math than is expected of us. But if we have a known passface database off 100 faces, a password is five faces, and verification is choosing 1 face from a random 9, 5 times. The set size can't be 100 though can it, since in each challenge there's only 9 options. It's not the same 9 though so I don't think log2(9^5) or log2(100^5) are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a set of 100 total unique faces and have to choose 5 different faces to represent your passface, then the total number of possible face combinations is 100 x 99 x 98 x 97 x 96, or 9,034,502,400.  Similar to your 100^5 estimate, but slightly less because you can't choose the same face more than once.  Some people would say this represents the possible entropy (e.g. 33 bits) of a passface in this scenario.

But that doesn't seem to be what you're asking.  You seem more interested in the probability of an attacker randomly guessing a passface using the normal authentication system.  If 9 faces are presented for selection then the attacker has a 1 in 9 chance of guessing the correct face.  If they have to choose the correct face from the 9 different presented face choices 5 times in a row then the number of possible choices are the 9^5 you mention, or 59,049.

I'm not sure what you mean by "it's not the same 9 [faces] though".  If you mean each of the 5 grids don't contain the same 'decoy' faces along with 1 valid face then you're correct.  Each of the 5 grids contain a different selection of decoy faces.  But the 9^5 possibilities figure still works.  You can comment or edit your question if you meant something else.